# Jquery can't recognize item

Tags: jquery, html

I am moving a li to ul from another ul on click and this can be two way. After I replaced class, jquery is miss recognizing replaced class.

```
$('.web').click(function() {
    console.log('Append to deposit');
    $('#deposit').append($(this).addClass('deposit').removeClass('web'));
});

$('.deposit').click(function() {
    console.log('Append to web');
    $('#web').append($(this).addClass('web').removeClass('deposit'));
});
```

The result is always **Append to web**, because when page called there is not any item in web class.

Question is why is not moving 2 ways and how will I fix it?

Comment: At the time `$(".deposit").on(...)` is called, the element does not have the `deposit` class. You need to delegate the event.

Comment: Thanks, learned about delegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentionned in comments, you just need to [delegate the event](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for those "dynamic" elements. They are considered "dynamic" because they move in the DOM structure.

So the changes in your code are simple:

```
$('#web').on('click','.web',function() {
  console.log('Append to deposit');
  $('#deposit').append($(this).addClass('deposit').removeClass('web'));
});

$('#deposit').on('click','.deposit',function() {
  console.log('Append to web');
  $('#web').append($(this).addClass('web').removeClass('deposit'));
});
```